# Moving a portable version of texlive disrupts access to fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive

I moved my portable installation of texlive from being directly under `C:\` in Windows 10 to `C:\Users\username\software\`. As a result, `fontspec` can no longer find the fonts. When I run `fc-cache -fv` in the command prompt, it returns this:

```
C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype: skipping, no such directory
C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype: skipping, no such directory
```

Meaning it still looks in the previous location of texlive, directly under `C:\`. What do I need to do to update the font search locations?

Comment: the  config file is normally in texmf-var in fonts/conf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I edited the file `fonts.conf` directly in a text editor. I wonder if it's possible for it to self update somehow. I've noticed that prior to 2018, I could freely move or rename my portable texlive folder with no consequences.

Comment: Sorry. As the file is in texmf-var there is probably a script to create/update it somewhere. But I never had a portable installation so I don't know the details. Ask on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to convert your comment about the config file into an answer (specifying that the file paths in the file need to be changed manually)?

Comment: As I just wrote: I don't know the details and I don't know if the paths should be changed there (actually I doubt it, files in texmf-var are often overwritten).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, but I did and it worked.

Comment: I don't doubt that it worked. But I don't know if it is permanent or if the next update will overwrite the settings again.

Comment: Sorry, the font paths for xetex have always been hard-coded. Are you sure that you made use of xetex prior to the 2018 release? So I think that Ulrike should turn her comment into an answer.